# Turn off Hystrix functionality

Tags: hystrix

I am integrating Hystrix in an application. That application is already in production and we will be testing out hystrix integration work in sandbox before we will push it to production. 
My question is that is there any way to turn on/off hystrix functionality using some configuration setting?

Comment: Maybe setting circuitBreaker.forceClosed to true or circuitBreaker.enabled to false will do.

Answer (score 12):

There is no single setting for this. You'll need to set multiple parameters to disable Hystrix.

See https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration for the configuration options:

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.strategy=SEMAPHORE
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.semaphore.maxConcurrentRequests=100000 # basically 'unlimited'
hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled=false 
hystrix.command.default.circuitBreaker.enabled=false
hystrix.command.default.fallback.enabled=false
```

Please double check your version of Hystrix for the available parameters.

Comment: I will be putting this to test very soon.

Comment: Btw, why does it matter to change set strategy to SEMAPHORE?

Comment: Using semaphores avoids creating new threads for your wrapped Hystrix commands. As you don't limit your concurrent requests in this disabled setup, you would otherwise end up with a lot of threads.

Answer (score 11):

This is all what you need:

```
# Disable Circuit Breaker (Hystrix)

spring:
  cloud:
    circuit:
      breaker:
        enabled: false

hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      circuitBreaker:
        enabled: false
```

Comment: Thanks, This is the most correct and simple solution, it works perfect with me.

Answer (score 3):

As ahus1 said, there is no single way to disable Hystrix entirely. To disable it in our application, we decided it was cleanest and safest to put a HystrixCommand in a wrapper class, and that wrapper class only exposed the parts of the HystrixCommand that we used (in our case, the execute() method). When constructing the wrapper class, we pass it a Callable that contains the code we want executed, and if Hystrix is disabled (according to our own config value), we simply call that Callable without ever creating a HystrixCommand. This avoids executing any Hystrix code whatsoever and makes it easier to say that Hystrix isn't affecting our application *at all* when it's disabled.

Comment: This is a pretty neat solution. I was looking for an idea for the same problem and will use this. It's the first time we're introducing Hystrix and it would be useful to be able to turn it off/on easily.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of  ways to achieve this-

1. Doing this for your every group including default. Although this will not disable hystrix(it will only keep the circuit closed all the time) but you will achieve the same result-

   `hystrix.command.{group-key}.circuitBreaker.forceClosed=false`
2. If you are using java, you can create an around advice over *@HystrixCommand* annotation and bypass hystrix execution based upon a flag.

Java Code for #2-

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.annotation.HystrixCommand)")
public void hystrixCommandAnnotationPointcut() {
}

@Around("hystrixCommandAnnotationPointcut()")
public Object methodsAnnotatedWithHystrixCommand(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
Object result = null;
Method method = AopUtils.getMethodFromTarget(joinPoint);
if ((System.getProperty(enable.hystrix).equals("true")) {
    result = joinPoint.proceed();
} else {
    result = method.invoke(joinPoint.getTarget(), joinPoint.getArgs());
}
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The only problem with the second approach is that it will trigger the aspect in actual HystrixCommandAspect as the Pointcuts would be the same for both your Aspect and HystrixCommandAspect.

Comment: @SherinSyriac Yes. My advice will only work around the methods annotated with actual HystrixCommand annotation. This way I can control whether hystrix kicks in or not. I am editing my answer to include my pointcut so that it becomes more lucid.

Comment: Are you declaring <bean  class="com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.aop.aspectj.HystrixCommandAspect"/>? Then I think the HystrixCommandAspect will be triggered more than one time. This is because both aspects have same pointcut.Also how do you make sure the order in which your aspect and HystrixCommandAspect is triggered if they use the same pointcut?

Comment: Yes, I have created a bean as you mentioned but I have not specified any advice order. I guess it's by chance that my custom advice is always executing first.
I also tried @Order after reading your comment to see if I can get my custom advice to run after the original advice defined on HystricCommand annotation but couldn't get it to work. My advice is always executing first.
Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

If your Project is spring Managed you can comment the bean definition of hystrixAspect in applicationContext.xml
Comment the following line

> bean id="hystrixAspect"class="com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.aop.aspectj.HystrixCommandAspect"/>

This will remove Hystrix from your project.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this situation where I wanted to completely turnoff Hystrix using a single property (We use IBM uDeploy to manage dynamic properties). We are using javanica library built on top of Hystrix

1. Create a Configuration class which creates the HystrixCommandAspect

@Configuration
        public class HystrixConfiguration{

```
@Bean(name = "hystrixCommandAspect")
@Conditional(HystrixEnableCondition.class)
public HystrixCommandAspect hystrixCommandAspect(){ 
      return new HystrixCommandAspect()}
}
```

2. And the conditional class would be enabled based on a system property.

public class HystrixEnableCondition implements Condition{

  @Override
  public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata){
    return 
       "YES".equalsIgnoreCase(
           context.getEnvironment().getProperty("circuitBreaker.enabled")) ||

       "YES".equalsIgnoreCase(
           System.getProperty("circuitBreaker.enabled"));
  }

 }

Answer (score 0):

setting
`hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.strategy=SEMAPHORE`
is enough.
Additionally  you may or should disable also the timeout threads
with `hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled=false`